# Remove 'Layout Orientation' from NSTextView context menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I have a `NSTextView` which has a ruler attached showing line numbers. If the user uses the 'Layout Orientation' -> 'Vertical' context menu, things go wonky. The applications intended purpose does not support a Vertical orientation anyway, so I would like to remove this context menu.

So far I have subclassed an `NSTextView` and overwrote the `defaultMenu` action:

```
+ (NSMenu *) defaultMenu
{
    // Get our default menu
    NSMenu * contextMenu =
        [NSTextView defaultMenu];

    for(NSInteger menuItemIndex = contextMenu.itemArray.count - 1;
        menuItemIndex != -1;
        --menuItemIndex)
    {
        NSMenuItem * menuItem =
            [contextMenu itemAtIndex: menuItemIndex];

        NSLog(@"%ld %@, %@",
              menuItemIndex,
              NSStringFromSelector(menuItem.action),
              menuItem.title);
    } // End of menuItem loop

    return contextMenu;
} // End of defaultMenu
```

My original thought was that I could remove the menu item with a specific selector, but unfortunately the 'Layout Orientation' is a submenu, so it has the `submenuAction:` selector.

I could still remove the menu by comparing the title, but that seems like a poor way to do this and would probably break in a localized environment.

Any suggestions as to PROPERLY go about removing menu items from the NSTextView context menu? (Removing by index also seems hacky, as that could possible break on different versions of the OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each submenu menuitem has a menu. Scan the submenus for action `changeLayoutOrientation:`.

You can disable the layout orientation menu items by implementing `validateUserInterfaceItem:`.

```
- (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id<NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)anItem {
    if ([anItem action] == @selector(changeLayoutOrientation:))
        return NO;
    return [super validateUserInterfaceItem:anItem];
}
```